# Broken random scoring with elastic search when specific fields are used

Tags: elasticsearch

I am encountering a weird problem with random scoring in elastic and it appears only when fields are used:

```
{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 50,
    "fields":   { "fields": [ "id", "name"] },
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": { "must_not": { "term": { "disabled": true}}}
                },
            "random_score": {
                    "seed": 123456
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then this construct is used, _score of every document is 1!
Removing "fields" starts popping up some items with top one having _score of 16775988. I guess I do not understand the interaction between fields and scoring, how does one affect the other?

Thanks for your help!